# Can not access interface default implementation method from within derived class

Tags: interface, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

I am trying the new features of C#8 and i have come to this problem.
Having an interface with a default implementation method , i am defining a derived class that calls the said method inside it (constructor or proprietary method).
Why am i not able to see the interface method ?

**Interface with default implementation method**

```
interface IA{
   public void DoStuff()
   {
   }
}
```

**Derived class that should contain interface method**

```
class A:IA
{
   public void DoSomeOtherStuff()
   {
      this.//DoStuff() does not exist !!!
      // I could write like below but it beats the purpose
      // IA a=this;
     //  a.DoStuff()
   }
}
```

My question is , why isn't `this` treated as abiding to the interface contract? Why does it not have access to the default impl method ?

Comment: That's how it was designed, default interface implementation is meant to be there to allow devs to add methods to an interface without breaking clients.

Comment: There's a very good reason for this - if multiple interfaces have the same method, the compiler (and the developer) would have no idea which one to call. That's what makes inheritance in C++ so painful. You need to access those implementations the same way you would explicit interface implementations, by first casting to the interface

Comment: So i can not access defualt imp methods from derived classes unless i cast `this` to the target interface.

Comment: That's what the docs and the duplicate says. If you think about it a bit, you'll see that even you won't be able to tell which method would be called without the explicit cast

Comment: Ok you can post answer , i will accept it.